# Workaround for horizontal scroll bar obscuring single line code markdowns

Tags: feature-request, design, markdown

Occasionally this happens on chrome from a mac:

[image]

Single line code markdowns can thereafter be difficult to read. Clicking elsewhere on the page doesn't seem to 'undo' this. My workaround is to double click the code and paste it into the address bar where it's easily read. Is there a better way around this?

Or could either the scroll bar height be reduced or the height of the markdown box be increased?

Note: example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766131/embed-pdf-at-full-height)

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SO: [One-line codeblock scrollbars won't disappear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326473/4642212). That question and its linked questions (right sidebar) contain possible solutions.